# Improving unidirectional path tracer convergence

Tags: graphics, 3d, rendering, raytracing

I implemented a non-naive unidirectional path tracer inside my software.

**My scene has only one light(the sun). After 1 hour of rendering(2000 samples/pixel) I get this result:**:

[image]

Is there a way to improve the convergence, or no choice I need to switch to BDPT or MLT?
Here my code. The **gatherRadiance** function is called multiple time inside a given pixel. I perform a cumulative moving average. The intersector mentioned is simply a wrapper of Embree.

```cpp
// The intersection properties.
struct IntersectionProperties
{
    Math::Vec3 P;
    Math::Vec3 deltaP;
    Math::Vec3 N;
};


//@See: https://www.scratchapixel.com/lessons/3d-basic-rendering/global-illumination-path-tracing/global-illumination-path-tracing-practical-implementation.html
inline Math::Vec3 uniformSphericalSample(const float &r1, const float &r2)
{
    float sinTheta = sqrtf(1 - r1 * r1);
    float phi = Math::Pi2.getValue() * r2;
    float x = sinTheta * cosf(phi);
    float z = sinTheta * sinf(phi);

    return Math::Vec3(x, r1, z);
}

//@See : https://www.scratchapixel.com/lessons/3d-basic-rendering/global-illumination-path-tracing/global-illumination-path-tracing-practical-implementation.html
inline void createCoordinateSystem(const Math::Vec3 &N, Math::Vec3 &Nt, Math::Vec3 &Nb)
{
    if (std::fabs(N.x) > std::fabs(N.y))
        Nt = Math::Vec3(N.z, 0, -N.x) / sqrtf(N.x * N.x + N.z * N.z);
    else
        Nt = Math::Vec3(0, -N.z, N.y) / sqrtf(N.y * N.y + N.z * N.z);

    Nb = glm::cross(N, Nt);
}

inline IntersectionProperties buildIntersectionProperties(const Math::Ray& ray, const Intersector::IntersectionInfo& info)
{
    // Compute the intersection properties
    const auto mesh = info.object;
    const auto P = ray.getPoint(info.meshIntersectData.t);

    #define PRIMITIVE_NB_VTX 3
    const unsigned int triStartIdx = info.meshIntersectData.primId * PRIMITIVE_NB_VTX;

    const auto v1 = mesh->buildTransformedVertexFromIndex(triStartIdx);
    const auto v2 = mesh->buildTransformedVertexFromIndex(triStartIdx + 1);
    const auto v3 = mesh->buildTransformedVertexFromIndex(triStartIdx + 2);

    const float invArea = mesh->getPrecomputedInvArea()[info.meshIntersectData.primId];
    const Math::Vec3 coefs = Math::interpolate(v1.position, v2.position, v3.position, P, invArea);

    // Eye vector
    const Math::Vec3 V = -ray.getDirection();

    IntersectionProperties props;
    // The position.
    props.P = P;

    // The normal.
    props.N = glm::normalize(
        (v1.normal * coefs.x) + (v2.normal * coefs.y) + (v3.normal * coefs.z)
    );

    if (glm::dot(props.N, V) < 0.0f)
        props.N *= -1;

    // Offseted position to avoid self intersections.
    props.deltaP = P + (props.N * 0.01f);

    return props;
}

// THE MAIN FUNCTION ----------------------------------------------
Integrator::Spectrum OfflineRenderer::gatherRadiance(const Math::Ray& ray, unsigned int depth)
{
    Intersector::IntersectionInfo intersectInfo;
    m_intersector->intersect(ray, intersectInfo);

    if (intersectInfo.object == nullptr)
        return RGBFColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);

    // Get intersection properties
    const IntersectionProperties isectProps = buildIntersectionProperties(ray, intersectInfo);

    // Compute sun direct lighting contribution.
    RGBFColor directCont = RGBFColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    {
        // Sun properties.
        static const glm::vec3 sunDirection = glm::normalize(glm::vec3(0.980282f, -0.190809, -0.0513746));
        static const RGBFColor sunColor = RGBFColor(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
        static const float sunIntensity = 11.0f;

        const float NoL = glm::dot(isectProps.N, -sunDirection);
        if (NoL > 0.0f)
        {
            // Cast shadow ray.
            Math::Ray shadowRay(isectProps.deltaP, -sunDirection, 99999999.9f);
            const float occlusionStrength = m_intersector->occlusion(shadowRay);

            // Light radiance.
            directCont = sunColor * sunIntensity;

            // Cosine term.
            directCont *= NoL;

            // Diffuse brdf.
            directCont *= Math::InvPi.getValue();

            // Multiply by visibility.
            directCont *= (1.0f - occlusionStrength);
        }
    }


    RGBFColor indirectCont = RGBFColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);

    #define MAX_DEPTH 32
    if (++depth < MAX_DEPTH)
    {
        // Generate random sample.
        //@ See : https://www.scratchapixel.com/lessons/3d-basic-rendering/global-illumination-path-tracing/global-illumination-path-tracing-practical-implementation.html
        const Math::Vec3 axis = isectProps.N;
        Math::Vec3 axisT, axisB;
        createCoordinateSystem(axis, axisT, axisB);

        const float randomAzimut = m_nbGenerator.generateUnsignedNormalized();
        const float randCosLatitude = m_nbGenerator.generateUnsignedNormalized();

        const Math::Vec3 sample = uniformSphericalSample(randCosLatitude, randomAzimut);

        const Math::Vec3 rotatedSample = Math::Vec3(
            sample.x * axisB.x + sample.y * axis.x + sample.z * axisT.x,
            sample.x * axisB.y + sample.y * axis.y + sample.z * axisT.y,
            sample.x * axisB.z + sample.y * axis.z + sample.z * axisT.z);
        //

        // Compute reflected ray.
        const Math::Ray reflectedRay(Math::Ray(isectProps.deltaP, rotatedSample));

        // Indirect lighting.
        indirectCont = gatherRadiance(reflectedRay, depth);

        // Diffuse brdf.
        indirectCont *= Math::InvPi.getValue();

        // Cosine term.
        const float NoL = glm::dot(isectProps.N, reflectedRay.getDirection());
        indirectCont *= NoL;

        #define HEMISPHERICAL_NORMALIZATION  (2.0f * Math::Pi.getValue())
        indirectCont *= HEMISPHERICAL_NORMALIZATION;
    }

    return directCont + indirectCont;
}
// ----------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Rendering the scene with only AO with 200 samples (at 1600x1200) takes on my AMD Ryzen 9 3900XCPU using Embree 3.13.5 (without ISPC) already approx. 100 seconds - your time sounds not too unrealistically. A better sampling strategy such as BDPT should lead to faster convergence -> https://www.pbr-book.org/3ed-2018/Light_Transport_III_Bidirectional_Methods/Bidirectional_Path_Tracing